# Perl Syntax combining `foreach` and `if`: Shouldn't it work, i.e.: Why doesn't it work?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, syntax, max

Trying to get the maximum in an array that cannot contain negative numbers I tried:

```perl
my @v;
#...
my $max = 0;
$max = $_
    if ($_ > $max)
        foreach (@v);
```

I get a syntax error with perl 5.18.2.

However (1) `statement($_) foreach (@v);` and (2) `$max = $_ if ($_ > $max);` are both OK, and they do what they are supposed to do.

So if (1) and (2) are both valid statements, why can't they be combined in the pattern used for (1)?

Just that noone needs to suggest that; here's how I solved the problem using a different syntax:

```perl
foreach (@v) {
    $max = $_
        if ($_ > $max);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So if (1) and (2) are both valid statements, why can't they be combined in the pattern used for (1)?

The postfix syntax (aka statement modifier), which you are using here, just does not support this kind of statement.

The [documentation says](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) (emphasis mine):

> Any **simple statement** may optionally be followed by a SINGLE modifier, just before the terminating semicolon (or block ending).

As for your task itself: getting the max value from an array is a very common requirement. A simple and standard approach uses [function `max()` from core module `List::Util`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#max):

```
use List::Util qw/max/;
my @v;
my $max = max 0, @v;
```

Comment: OK, I did not realize that these are "statement *modifiers*", a concept that seems to be unique to Perl syntax and its parser. As for `List::Util`: I wasn't aware of that, and when looking up it's implementation, I realized that it's part of Perl's core (still `perldoc -f max` does not find a match), and it's implemented in machine language (C). To make your answer perfect: s/dos/does/, because I cannot do one-character-edits.

Comment: `max 0, @v` would be a closer equivalent.

Comment: @ikegami: ah yes that's a good point. I did not pay attention to the initial assignment of `$max` in the question. Fixed.

Comment: It's still possible that the OP would prefer `max @v`, though. Didn't meant to imply otherwise

Comment: @ikegami: at least this is consistent with their original attempted code...

Comment: @U. Windl, Re "*a concept that seems to be unique to Perl syntax and its parser.*", Python has similar syntax, though it allows them to be chained as you wish to do here. (They also return a value, so they're really some kind of low-precedence infix operator.)

Answer (score 1):

I will add this more generic answer, because wanting to combine `for` & `if` statement modifiers is pretty common, not only for trivial cases where you can use a (much faster) CPAN module.
The reason why you might want to not do the standard foreach that uses a block, is that a block costs time, which might be insignificant if what happens inside the loop is slow, but might be over 10% of overhead if you are doing something like a simple assignment. e.g. this simple example:

```
my @v = map { rand } ( 1..100 );
cmpthese(-2, {
    postfix => sub {
        my $last;
        $last = $_ for @v;
    },
    block => sub {
        my $last;
        foreach (@v) {$last = $_}
    },
});
```

Gives me:

> ```
>             Rate   block postfix
> block   214369/s      --    -11%
> postfix 241751/s     13%      --
> ```

So... while you cannot use two statement modifiers (postfix `if`, `for`), most of the time you can replace the `for` with a `map`, retaining the speed of a block-less loop. For example OP's example would be `map {$max = $_ if $_ > $max} @v` and benchmarked:

```
my @v = map { rand } ( 1..100 );
cmpthese(-2, {
    map => sub {
        my $max = 0;
        map {$max = $_ if $_ > $max} @v;
    },
    foreach => sub {
        my $max = 0;
        foreach (@v) {$max = $_ if $_ > $max}
    },
});
```

gives:

> ```
>             Rate foreach     map
> foreach 205585/s      --    -13%
> map     236303/s     15%      --
> ```

As I said, in the specific case, you should definitely use `List::Util` which is written in C and will be an order of magnitude faster...

Comment: Where does `cmpthese` come from? When I try, I get "undefined subroutine &main::cmpthese called ...".

Comment: It's Benchmark, a very useful core package: https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html . Add `use Benchmark qw(:all);`.

Comment: Actually I'm quite surprised by the benchmark results: I thought Perl compiles the code and the braces would just group syntax elements. However it seems braces actually create additional code!

Comment: @U.Windl Curly braces setup & teardown a scope, so they add overhead. You would hope that in my example a compiler would see that you don't actually use the extra scope for anything, but compilers don't seem to be THAT optimizing. Same with postfix if/unless, they save you some overhead compared to the block versions.

Comment: On "compilers don't seem to be THAT optimizing": gcc with default settings optimized `printf("%c", blabla)` to `putchar(blabla)` for a long time now. I was rather surprised not to find a call to `printf` when viewing the assembly language... ;-)